# Multiple Case Statements Scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Sample Data:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
| CaseID | StartDate | EndDate  | ReviewDate | Event |
+--------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
|     56 | 7/2/2017  | 7/2/2017 | 7/2/2017   | pre   |
|     56 |           |          |            | post  |
+--------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
```

I need to write a `case statement` when event=post and startdate, enddate and reviewdate are null I need to consider the dates in event=pre else  post

How can I deal this scenario

Comment: Please provide a sample data and desired output

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Comment: Try to avoid images, as we can not copy the text.

Comment: Just a side note. Blank, or `''` isn't the same as `NULL`. You're question still doesn't make any sense. What do you mean, you need to consider the dates in event =pre else post? Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: i need to show the data only for Event=Post but if the date fields are blank as above i need to consider the dates from Event=Pre

Comment: Is there only 1 and always 1 pre and post for each case ID or can a case ID have multiple pre or post events?

Comment: You literally wrote out the entire statement you need in plaintext english. We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a self join... no case statement since there is always 1 pre and 1 post. Here are two ways.

**This query does just what your requirements stated**

```
declare @table table (CaseID int, StartDate date, EndDate date, ReviewDate date, [Event] varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
(56,'20170702','20170702','20170702','pre'),
(56,NULL,NULL,NULL,'post'),
(57,'20170704',NULL,NULL,'pre'),
(57,'20170705','20170705','20170705','post'),
(58,NULL,'20170709',NULL,'pre'),
(58,'20170709',NULL,'20170709','post')


select 
    t1.CaseID
    ,case when t1.startDate is null and t1.EndDate Is Null and t1.ReviewDate is null then  t2.StartDate  else t1.StartDate end as StartDate
    ,case when t1.startDate is null and t1.EndDate Is Null and t1.ReviewDate is null then  t2.EndDate  else t1.EndDate end as EndDate
    ,case when t1.startDate is null and t1.EndDate Is Null and t1.ReviewDate is null then  t2.ReviewDate  else t1.ReviewDate end as ReviewDate
from
    @table t1
left join
    @table t2 on
    t2.CaseID = t1.CaseID 
    and t2.Event <> t1.Event
where
    t1.[Event] = 'post'
```

**This one basically merges the rows for NULL dates**

```
select 
    t1.CaseID
    ,coalesce(t1.StartDate, t2.StartDate) as StartDate
    ,coalesce(t1.EndDate,t2.EndDate) as EndDate
    ,coalesce(t1.ReviewDate,t2.EndDate) as ReviewDate
from
    @table t1
left join
    @table t2 on
    t2.CaseID = t1.CaseID 
    and t2.Event <> t1.Event
where
    t1.[Event] = 'post'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do self left join with post values and do get results as below:

```
Select t1.CaseID, case when coalesce(t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate, t2.ReviewDate) is null then t1.StartDate else t2.StartDate end as StartDate
    ,case when coalesce(t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate, t2.ReviewDate) is null then t1.EndDate else t2.EndDate end as EndDate
    ,case when coalesce(t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate, t2.ReviewDate) is null then t1.ReviewDate else t2.ReviewDate end as ReviewDate
    from #table t1 
left join #table t2
    on t1.CaseID = t2.CaseID
where t1.[Event] = 'pre'
    and t2.[Event] = 'post'
```